# Very slow remote page load performance in QtWebKit (Windows)

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I get very slow load times on QtWebKit on Windows 7, through ADSL.
I am using the Qt Demo Browser, on a Core2 Quad, 64 bit Windows 7, 4GB ram, 2gb processor.
through a VPN.
Simplest example: google search page takes ~18 seconds to load, 
compared to 2.5 on Chrome (cash cleared).
On larger pages, with scripts etc. it is worse.
I tried Qt 4.6 and also the Qt 4.7 beta, but don't see any difference.
I see the same results with Arora browser.
Are there any settings, or patches that can be applied to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that DNS resolution for QtWebKit on Windows is much slower than the exact same code running on OSX or Ubuntu. In our case, switching from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" resulted in much improved performance.